# performance issue in arraylist.add(objects)

Tags: arraylist

Could you please provide me the kind of performance issue arises in the following statement. How to resolve it.

```
ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
a.add("myname");
a.add(new myClass()); //here I am trying to assign the object to the list. 
a.add(new Integer(50));
```

Comment: What performance issue? Why do you think this is a performance issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight performance impact when pulling items out of the array list since you have to cast from object to the concrete type. It's usually better to use Generic typed lists to avoid the casting. It's however unlikely to cause a problem for small lists.

Answer (score 0):

[**Boxing and Unboxing**](http://codebetter.com/raymondlewallen/2005/07/29/boxing-and-unboxing-for-beginners/)

> Any reference or value type that is added to an ArrayList is
>   implicitly upcast to Object. If the items are value types, they must
>   be boxed when they are added to the list, and unboxed when they are
>   retrieved. Both the casting and the boxing and unboxing operations
>   decrease performance; the effect of boxing and unboxing can be very
>   significant in scenarios where you must iterate over large
>   collections.

Use [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5bx6xee.aspx) instead.